# Javascript check how function is invoked

Tags: javascript, function, reflection

is there a way to check how some function is called (and change the output according to that) ?

I have some object that should have the string "," as separator when concatenated, how can i overload toString function in a way that it put separator between two strings?

For example alert ( a + b ) when "a" and "b" are my object will invoke their toString() functions.
Now i would that the first invocation should sees that the caller function ( the plus ) will concatenate the toString() of my object and so put separator (eg : "," ).
The second invocation on the other hand should sees that it is the second operator of the function plus, so even if this function is still concatenating my object the "b".toString() is a simple toString().

If a.toString() = "foo" and b.toString() = "bar" , i would that ( a + b ) will equal to "foo.bar" and not "foo.bar."

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour ?

Comment: Abusing `.toString()` isn't really a good way to overload operators, as JavaScript doesn't support that. Why don't you create a `.concat()` or a `.add()` method?

Comment: you could overload [].toString to do this, but "".toString can't tell which var is which (right or left)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself am also obsessed with beautiful syntax.

```
  // How wonderful, if this:
cursorPosition + playerPosition + targetPosition

  // Could output to something like this:
"(14:68), (22:56), (76:32)"
```

It's a nice idea, but I don't think it's practical. The best-practice solution is nearly as wonderfully simple:

```
display(cursorPosition, playerPosition, targetPosition)
"(14:68), (22:56), (76:32)"
```

Importantly, with this technique (defining a display function), toString acts conventionally -- which means you don't need to worry about your comma stuff toying with your conventional use of toString:

```
console.log("Your location is " +playerPosition+ " and the target is " +targetPosition+" which is far away");
"Your location is (22:56) and the target is (76:32) which is far away"
```

---

### In my opinion, the situation should be handled this way:

```
function Position(x,y){  
  this.x = x ?x :0;
  this.y = y ?y :0;
}
Position.prototype.toString = function(){  return '(' +this.x+ ':' +this.y+ ')'  };

var pos1 = new Position(22,40);
var pos2 = new Position(18,24);
var pos3 = new Position(84,46);
var pos4 = new Position(32,64);

function display(){
  var tests = [];
  for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i+=1) 
    tests.push( arguments[i].toString() );
  return tests.join(', ');
}

console.log(display( pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4 ));
```

Which outputs:

```
(22:40), (18:24), (84:46), (32:64)
```

Comment: I agree with your solution, and with the other people who are saying that the better solution is to use default syntax, in general case it's true.
But IMHO sometimes the syntax is important for a programmer as GUI for an end user, because a "better" syntax could help to provide better expressivity.

For that reason i am thinking to follow this article http://www.2ality.com/2011/12/fake-operator-overloading.html